# I can not import `commands` in my project now

Tags: python

In my project I want to import the commands, so I put the bellow code in my project:

```
import commands
```

but however there I get error:

```
No module named commands less... (⌘F1) 
This inspection detects names that should resolve but don't. Due to dynamic dispatch and duck typing, this is possible in a limited but useful number of cases. Top-level and class-level items are supported better than instance items.
```

Comment: can you provide your Python's version there?

Comment: Are you using python 3?

Comment: I use Python3.5.2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the documentation:

> Deprecated since version 2.6: The commands module has been removed in
>   Python 3. Use the subprocess module instead.

You can follow this link:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/commands.html

Comment: Perhaps see also https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html?highlight=subprocess#legacy-shell-invocation-functions which explains in more detail how exactly to replace `commands` with corresponding `subprocess` calls; though you should probably also be looking into replacing those legacy calls with `subprocess.run()`

Answer (score 2):

The `commands` module has been removed in python3, you can check [there](https://docs.python.org/2/library/commands.html):

> Deprecated since version 2.6: The commands module has been removed in Python 3. Use the **subprocess** module instead.